# Update the result/status of a cucumber test in run time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Folks, I want to achieve the following: While I am running a cucumber scenario, a particular edge case can occur, when that edge case occurs the step fails and all subsequent steps skip and the scenario fails, What I want to do is when I encounter the edge case I want to set the status of the scenario to skipped/passed and dont want the scenario to fail. Any ideas around how to achieve this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea. It sounds like your tests are non-deterministic.

See [Eradicating Non-Determinism in Tests](http://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your Gherkin scenarios should be fully independent from each other. They shouldn't rely on some edge case that isn't directly stated in `Given` or `When` steps of the scenario or it's background.

You should create 2 scenarios that may look like:

```
Given edge case doesn't happen
...
Then A happens
```

```
Given edge case happens
...
Then B happens
```

Comment: @NeorubyAlto if you think that this approach won't work for you, then say in your question what edge case do you have.